# Como criar listas em for?

Tags: python

Queria saber se tem como criar varias listas em for.
exemplo, o cara coloca no input (num_jogadores) "2" então eu queria cirar
2 listas ------ lista1 = [] e lista2 = []

```
num_jogadores = int(input("digite o numero de jogadores: "))

for i in range(0, num_jogadores):
  lista[i] = []
#criar listas com o tanto de num_jogadores
```

Comment: Troque `lista[i] = []` por `lista.append([])`. Porém acredito que o ideal seria trabalhar com lista de objetos.

Answer (score 0):

O melhor jeito de fazer isso é utilizando uma [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```py
n = int(input('Digite o número de jogadores: '))

lista = [[] for _ in range(n)]
```